# hardware airplane switch on supposedly causing wireless connections to not work

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, dell, connection

I have been having this issue when I updated to linux ubuntu 19.04 on my very old Dell latitude D830, one error I've been having is the internet connection not working, because wifi doesnt connect. I've tried every solution in here so far with NONE changing anything.

My original problem is that tge internet connection, wifi, is disabled, and it says UNAVAILABLE, tryinf to enable it doesnt work. I cant use tethering or usb or bluetooth because the only way I get internet is wifi and those options turn it off from my phone.

output of `sudo rfkill list`:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
                Soft blocked: no
                Hard Blocked: no

1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
                Soft blocked: no
                Hard Blocked: no

2: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
                Soft blocked: no
                Hard Blocked: yes
3: dell-blueooth: Bluetooth
                Soft blocked: no
                Hard Blocked: yes
```

output of `ip link`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
            link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00

2: enp9s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
            link/ether 00:21:70:79:42:4b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

3: wlp12s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
            link/ether 00:22:5f:1c:59:62 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Again, every other solution i saw over here by googling didnt work, I typed more than a million commands for this problem to go, I actually encountered it earlier when i installed ubuntu 19.04, but I fixed it, but then after that by some months, i think around 2/3, it came back. and I have no way whatsoever to fix it, i even tried going back to what originally fixed it.

Comment: Please be specific as to what you've tried. I note in your messages the SATE is DOWN - ie. currently it won't work; but you didn't provide details as your chipset or anything. The d830 doesn't help as during the life of those laptops dell may have used 3-5 chipsets. Have a look at the documentation, ie. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide as it'll at minimum it'll provide device recognition & operation specs useful for us to help you.